# What is the norm of the single and double-layer potential operators in $\mathcal{L}(L^2(\partial \Omega),H^{1}(\partial \Omega))$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

Let $S$ the following *single layer potential* associated to the laplacian problem :

$$S[\varphi](x):= \int_{\partial \Omega} G(x-y) \varphi(y) d\sigma(y) , \quad \varphi \in L^2(\partial \Omega), \quad x \in \partial \Omega$$
where $\Omega$ is a bounded open domain with boundary of class $C^{1,s}$ ($0 < s < 1$) and $G(x):= - \frac{1}{4 \pi |x|}$ is the Green function of the Laplacian. It is well-known that $S$ is a bounded linear operator from $L^2(\partial \Omega)$ to $H^1(\partial \Omega)$, furthermore invertible.  **Is there a known value or bound on the norm
$||S||_{\mathcal{L}(L^2(\partial \Omega), H^1(\partial \Omega))} $ ?**

I'm also wondering the same for the *double layer potential* $D$ defined as

$$D[\varphi](x):= \int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla_y G(x-y) \cdot n(y) \varphi(y) d\sigma(y) , \quad \varphi \in L^2(\partial \Omega), \quad x \in \partial \Omega$$
which is a bounded linear operator from $L^2(\partial \Omega)$ to $L^2(\partial \Omega)$.

I'll be happy to provide further explications if necessary.

Comment: Do you mean a bound like the Poincare constant being the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian? Something along these lines?

Comment: I'm expecting a bound only depending on $\partial \Omega$. It would be even better if I could prove that $||S||_{\mathcal{L}(L^2(\partial \Omega), H^1(\partial \Omega))}=1$ but i'm guessing that's not true...